# Is the second sentence viable?

Tags: grammar

> 'Please take any book you like'.

> 'Thanks! I'll take this, this and that'.

Answer (score 1):

Since 'any book' is singular, the offerer means to give one book. The answer suggests a comical misunderstanding in literature. In an actual interaction, it would seem to be a purposeful disregard for the terms of the offer.

Comment: Note the usage 'Take any book that has a torn dustsheet into the discount section' where 'any book having property A' = 'all books having property A'. Though the 'any book' = 'any one book' reading is the default in OP's example, it's certainly noy mandated.

Comment: All this sidesteps the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the issue of whether the invitation was to take one book, or multiple books, the text "Thanks! I'll take this, this and that." is perfectly reasonable English. In context it is short for

> Thank you! I'll take this book, this book, and that book.

it is quite informal, but in no way invalid.